# ¿como hago para enviar mensajes en una misma aplicacion android con diferentes usuarios?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

soy nuevo en el tema de programacion movil, la pregunta es, tengo un proyecto en el cual un usuario A con la aplicacion instalada en su dispositivo debe enviarle un mensaje a un usuario B con la aplicacion instalada en otro dispositivo. Una misma aplicacion pero instalada en dispositivos diferentes. no encuentro post sobre eso, y no se como hacerlo, por favor podrian ayudarme, que librerias uso o que servicio. :/ uso android studio con firebase. (no tengo codigo escrito por que primero debo documentar)

Comment: Lo que pretendes es pasar información de una activity A a una activity B?

Comment: Nuevamente te sugerimos agregar más detalles, edita tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion. como dije antes soy novato, con muchas ganas de aprender. :)

Comment: de un dispositivo a otro? para empezar debes conectarlos de alguna manera, y la información deben de compartirla también, con una BD en servidor o conectándose entre ambos dispositivos, con bluetooth por ejemplo

Comment: utilizo como BD firebase. y el envio de mensajes debe hacerse por internet, algo como Mensaje ->servidor->receptor

Comment: @SebastianMosquera Todos tenemos ganas de aprender en el sitio, pero hasta el día de hoy no has realizado el [tour] o revisado [ask], te recomendamos realizarlo, es importante para que obtengas buenas respuestas, tu pregunta entra en la categoría de "demasiado amplia",  saludos.